# How to add unit function u(t) - u(t-2) as voltage source in LTSpice?

Tags: voltage, analog, ltspice, pulse, transient

As far as I know, we put the unit function as PULSE in LTSpice. If we have b.u(t) where b is a non zero integer, then we can put it in Von. But what if the function is u(t)-u(t-2)? And what if we want to know the current result in some particular time? Does anyone know how to do these?

Comment: Could **bv** (arbitrary behavioural voltage source) be a solution as it allows you to write a time-dependent voltage function?

Comment: If the function you're trying to model is b*u(t)-b*u(t-2), then why not create a PULSE voltage source that turns on at 0 and turns off at t=2? The only difference would be the rise and fall times of the voltage, but you should avoid discontinuities in LTSpice anyway. b*u(t)-c*u(t) would be a little trickier, but could easily be done with a PWL source.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Make that an answer, there already is the `u()` function, but please add a note about discontinuities.

Comment: @Stiddily Also make that an aswer, without leaving out the discontinuities warnings.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  I'll take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement perfectly ideal unit step functions because the transitions require a non-zero amount of time.  You can, however, get very good approximations if you keep these times small, but you should only use the smallest that is required by your application.

---

Your stated example of \$u(t)-u(t-2)\$ is quite simple, so it can be implemented with the PULSE() function you mentioned (either on a voltage or current source).  Any single pulse with a single height can be done this way.  You can change `Tdelay` to change the start of the pulse.  `Ton` then determines when the pulse ends, but it's a length so you'll have to do some math if `Tdelay` is non-zero.  `Von` sets the height for a voltage source (`I2` for a current source).  The rise and fall times (`Trise` and `Tfall`, respectively) are where the approximation kicks in and should be selected based on the sensitivity of your application.  To implement your example which lasts 2 full seconds, I chose the following:

[image]

You can also implement your example, and much more complex ones, using a behavioral source (either voltage or current).  If you already have an equation containing several Heaviside step functions at different amplitudes/heights, then this might be the more straightforward approach.  A voltage source is selected via the `bv` symbol and a current source via the `bi` or `bi2` symbols.  You simply edit the `V=F(...)` or `I=F(...)` text to insert your desired equation in place of `F(...)`.  The built-in LTspice help section titled "[B. Arbitrary behavioral voltage or current sources](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/B_Arbitrary_behavioral_voltage_or_current_sources_.htm)" gives you a list of valid functions and keywords you can use.  For this example, we're mostly interested in using the `u(x)` function and the `time` keyword as shown below.  The transition time approximation for these types of sources is **mainly** controlled by the `tripdv` and `tripdt` parameters.  I'm not going to delve too much into that and leave them at the defaults, but more information can be found [on the LTwiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=B_sources_(common_examples)).

[image]

---

We can run a 3 second transient simulation to compare the results between the two different approaches.

[image]

They look quite identical, but the edges are slightly different.  You can get a better look by zooming in.  I'll zoom in on the falling edge.

[image]

The PULSE() source version doesn't start falling down until 2.000001s, while the behavioral source version passes exactly through 2.000000s in the center of its transition.  This is because the PULSE() source doesn't start counting the 2 second length until the 1µs risetime at the beginning of the pulse completely finishes.  You can correct for this by making `Ton={2-2u}`,  or by changing the rise/fall times to nano (or even pico) seconds to make the error much more insignificant.

So depending on your application (sounds academic?) it might be better to use the behavioral version, especially if the equation you're trying to implement is quite complex.